# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView

Tags: react-native, expo

I added this lib:

```
https://github.com/mdjfs/expo-image-multiple-picker
```

then I get this err:

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.0",
    "@ramotion/react-native-circle-menu": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.8.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "d3-shape": "^3.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.3",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-multiple-picker": "^4.5.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-screen-capture": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^21.6.14",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.3",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^46.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "re-reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-fast-compare": "^3.2.0",
    "react-freeze": "^1.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.1",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-big-list": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-collapsible-tab-view": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-interactions": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.13",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "3.1.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.28",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-verification-input": "^2.0.6",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "recyclerlistview": "^3.0.5",
    "reselect": "^4.1.5",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.23",
    "@types/tinycolor2": "^1.4.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
```

so what can I do to prevent this error message ? thank you for your answers
................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Have you checked here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

This usually resolves by stopping the Metro bundler, deleting your `/node_modules` and `/ios/Pods` folders, running `yarn install && npx pod-install`, restarting the bundler -- `yarn start`, and rebuilding your application.

N.B. Replace `yarn` with `npm` if you are using npm for package management.